# neo4jclient to POCO objectGraph

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm starting to play with neo4jclient, and although I have found the wiki pages which show pulling out nodes etc. I'm a little confused how to take a slighlty more complex structure from the graphDB and reconstruct it into my POCO objects.

As an example, say I have the following graph:

[image: graphDB]

And I have the following classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<Sport> watches { get; set; }
    public List<Sport> plays { get; set; }

}

public class Sport
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public GoverningBody governingBody { get; set; }
}

public class GoverningBody
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Could somebody give me the c# code I would need to use to pull out "David", along with the sports he plays and the governing body for that sport. The end goal would be that the Person, Sport(s) and GoverningBody objects would all be populated so that I can use them as normal within the C# code.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

This is a very quick solution - you can create (in effect) an anonymous type in the `With` statement that you can parse into a result, for example, with the addition of a `SportAndGovern` class:

```
public class SportAndGovern
{
    public Sport Sport { get; set; }
    public GoverningBody Govern { get; set; }
}
```

You can execute this Cypher (I've not used parameterised stuff, *you should*) to get a person with a list of the sports they play - you do end up with duplicated Governing Bodies coming back, i.e. one for each Sport the person watches.

```
var query = Client.Cypher
    .Match("(p:Person {Name:'David'})")
    .OptionalMatch("(p)-[:PLAYS]->(s:Sport)<-[:GOVERNS]-(g:GoverningBody)")
    .With("p, Collect(Distinct {Sport: s, Govern: g}) as sportAndGovern")
    .Return((p, sportAndGovern) => new
    {
        Person = p.As<Person>(),
        SportAndGovern = Return.As<IEnumerable<SportAndGovern>>("sportAndGovern")
    });
```

Comment: Good suggestion. The `Collect(Distinct {Sport: s, Govern: g})` is new to me. Worth a +1. I love learning!

Answer (score 0):

This code should get you started

```
var userQuery = client.Cypher
    .Match("(n:Person { name: 'David'})-[:PLAYS]->(s:Sport)")
    .Return((n, s) => new
    {
        Peep = n.As<Person>(),
        Sports = s.CollectAsDistinct<Sport>()
    })
    .Results
    .FirstOrDefault();

var david = userQuery.Peep;
david.plays = userQuery.Sports.ToList();
```

SO looking at this in a little detail there are some points to note.

Firstly, `client` refers to an instance of `Neo4jClient` and assumes that you have previously initialised this.

Secondly, the query assumes that you only have one `Person` node where the `name` property has a value of `"David"`.

The `Return` clause projects the query results into an Anonymous type. It uses the `CollectAsDistinct` method to return an `IEnumerable<Sport>` collection. This translates into `COLLECT(distinct s)`  in Cypher to collect the `Sport` nodes.

Finally, it then users the anonymous type to build up a `Person` object to return.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks to make perfect sense. I understand your example is just to get me started, however, since positing the question it has dawned on me that the GoverningBody creates a circular reference (two sports are governed by the same GoverningBody). Would you be able to extend your example to show how that is handled correctly?

Comment: This is really more about the Cypher query. If I have time I'll take a look later. In the meantime you could try asking a more cypher specific question. If you then need help translating that to C#, it should be relatively trivial.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something, but the Cypher query seems to be: "match (p:Person {name: 'David'})-[:Watches]->(s:Sport)<-[:Governs]-(g:GoverningBody) return p,s,g" to bring back the items required, but pulling these into POCO object is puzzling me.

Comment: That query will give you multiple rows for David and so when deserializing you will have multiple objects with the name David. You could post-process the results or take the approach that @chris-skardon suggests in his answer. Either way you have some work to do to take the results returned and get them in the object graph structure you desire. Not sure it can be done in one query. Someone cleverer than me might be able to come up with something that does what you want!

Comment: Chris has kindly also responded with a couple of options over email. I'm putting together a working example of my preferred solution and will post once complete.